# How to store data with images in local for later use iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am able getting data from server and display on UITableView, It's working fine. But when I go to another tab and return to same tab it will call to server for data. I want to store data locally once get from server. 
Please suggest me your thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: you want to store permanent to device or just cache image for sometime like 1 week , 2 week

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the file on the device and this is possible in a few ways:

1. Store the files in the App its Documents directory
2. Store the files in the App its Library/Caches folder
3. Store the files in the App its Library/ folder

There are a few considerations for each option:

1. Files stored in the Documents folder are by default backed up by iCloud. You really have to think if this is necessary because you're eating up iCloud storage space from the user (for which he/she may pay).
2. Storing files in the Caches folder is a good way, but they may be deleted by iOS if the users disk is running low on space (therefore the name Cache).
3. Storing files in another (manually created) folder on the device will keep them as long as the app is installed. No iCloud backup or no removal by iOS

Getting the location of the specific folder can be done using:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Where you have to replace `NSDocumentDirectory` by NSLibraryDirectory when you want the NSURL to the Library folder.

Storing data is as easy as creating an NSURL which points to the location where you want to store the data and then call the `writeToURL:atomically:` method on the NSData you want to store.

Converting UIImages to NSData can be done using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to use the HJCache library for the temporally store images.

For that followings are the reasons to implement the HJCache open source library.

1. Make it easy to use asynchronously loaded images in iOS apps.
2. Make it easy to use a shared file cache.
3. Make memory management ‘just work’ according to Cocoa norms.
4. Support typical cases of viewing images, eg scrolling through a list of tweets showing the tweeters profile pic, swiping through a photo album loaded over the net.
5. Allow the library to be used for other kinds of data too.

For more detail and tutorial visit the [github](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache) and [author](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/) blog